# Strange number conversion while reading a csv file with ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, csv

i've got a strange problem in ruby on rails

There is a csv file, made with Excel 2003.

```
5437390264172534;Mark;5
```

I have a page with upload input and i read the file like this:

```
file = params[:upload]['datafile']
file.read.split("\n").each do |line|
  num,name,type = line.split(";")
  logger.debug "row: #{num} #{name} #{type}"
end
```

etc

So. finally i've got the following:

num = 5437...2534
name = Mark
type = 5

Why num has so strange value?

Also i tried to do like this:

```
   str = file.read

   csv = CSV.parse(str)

   csv.each do |line|
      RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER.info "@@@@@@@@ #{line.to_yaml}"
   end
```

but again i got

@@@@@@@@ --- 
- !str:CSV::Cell "5437...2534;Mark;5"

The csv file in win1251 (i can't change file encoding)
ruby file in UTF8

ruby version 1.8.4
rails version 2.0.2

Comment: forgot to write:

file = params[:upload]['datafile']

Answer (score 0):

If it indeed has a strange value, it probably has to to do with the code you *didn't* post. Edit your question, and include the smallest bit of code that will run independently and still produce your questionable output.

split() returns an array of strings. So the first value of your CSV file is a String, not a Bignum. Maybe you need `num.to_i`, or a test like `num.is_a?(Bignum)` somewhere in your code.

```
file = File.open("test.csv", "r")

    # Just getting the first line
    line = file.gets
    num,name,type = line.split(";")

    # split() returns an array of String
    puts num.class
    puts num

    # Make num a number
    puts num.to_i.class
    puts num.to_i

file.close
```

Running that file here gives me this:

```
$ ruby test.rb
String
5437390264172534
Bignum
5437390264172534
```

Comment: well. i need to get '5437390264172534' as a value of num and it doesn't matter for me what type of num or it's value is.

The problem is that the value is '5437390264172534' that is not correct(